# How to format the NumberTextBox without using locale?

Tags: dojo, formatting, number-formatting

I'm working on dojo's **NumberTextBox** and I have to format an amount field without using the locale. In order to do that, I tried **constraints and pattern**, however, I couldn't achieve the expected output.

Below is the expected output,

For example, If the user enters,

(i) 1234 - then **onblur** it should format it to 1,234.00

(ii) 1234.3432 - then **onblur** it should format it to 1,234.34

(iii) 1234.3489 - then **onblur** it should format it 1,234.35

(iv) 1234.3 - then **onblur** it should format it to 1,234.30

Could someone help me out on this?

EDIT:
The number can be anything (i.e hundreds, thousands and millions) and the pattern should be able to handle the comma separator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess was correct. You need to use `pattern`: `{pattern: '#,###.##'}`
You can find more details on the live doc : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/NumberTextBox

```js
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox){
    var myNumberTextBox = new NumberTextBox({
          name: "test",
          constraints: {pattern: '#,###.##'}
    }, "test");
    myNumberTextBox.startup();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not certain abou the number. It can be anything (i.e hundreds, thousands etc). How to create a pattern to deal with that (especially the separator)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give some sample?

Comment: The number can be anything. But the pattern should handle the comma separator.
For ex. 123,456,789.00

Comment: @VijinPaulraj I've updated the answer. Using `#` will do the trick